# Repeat a where clause statement for an Ecto query based on a list

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to create a search query using Ecto/postgres. Here's the first part of my query:

```
query = from l in Log,
  join: u in assoc(l, :user),
  where: u.id == ^current_user.id,
  select: l
```

The user can type in any number of terms (separated by white space) into a text box and then these terms are used to filter the result set. I'm using `String.split` to transform the original string into a set of where clauses (AND'd together) that are appended to the query:

```
search_term
|> String.split()
|> Enum.map( fn(term) ->
  query = from l in query,
    where: fragment("comment ~* ?", ^term)
end)
```

Except that this statement has no effect. I'm assuming that the `query` assignment only lives within the scope of the function. My mind is clouded by imperative thinking. How do I achieve this in a functional manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm assuming that the query assignment only lives within the scope of the function.

Yes, exactly.

You should use `Enum.reduce` for this, and pass the original query as the initial value of the accumulator:

```
search_term
|> String.split()
|> Enum.reduce(query, fn(term, query) ->
  from l in query, where: fragment("comment ~* ?", ^term)
end)
```